# Progressbar with Percentage in webpage .aspx file

Tags: c#

i want to make progress bar for downloading the file with change the percentage run time,

i have code but run time it'll not change the value of progress bar

then the download is complete the progress bar directly goes to 100%.

Please suggest me the Code for that her is my Sample Code.

```
private void DownloadFile(string url)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    client.DownloadProgressChanged += client_DownloadProgressChanged;

    client.DownloadFileCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);

    //  var url = _downloadUrls.Dequeue();
    string FileName = url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf("/") + 1,
                (url.Length - url.LastIndexOf("/") - 1));

    client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), Server.MapPath(".") + "\\" + FileName);
    //lblFileName.Text = url;

    return;
}

void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    double bytesIn = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
    double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
    double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100;
    Label1.Text = "test";
    //prg.Percentage = Convert.ToInt32(percentage);
    prg.Percentage = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DownloadFile(Sample URL);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With ASP.NET, server side code like this is evaluated completely on the server within the page request before returning to the client.  Your progress bar goes directly to 100% because the transfer is 100% complete before you see anything on the page.

Add some logging or add a breakpoint in the debugger where you set the percentage and, with a sufficiently large/slow transfer, you'll see that your progress is being updated properly.  You don't see it in the browser because there is nothing running on the client side to update the browser as this happens.  The browser rendering won't occur until after you are finished transferring the file and thus are set to 100%.

I'd suggest brushing up on the [ASP.NET page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.85).aspx) so you can better understand why this is happening.  Your Button1_Click is a postback event so it is being handled before the page rendering.

In order to see the progress updating as the transfer happens, you'll need a more sophisticated strategy using AJAX.  There are a few different approaches to implementing this in ASP.NET.

Here is an example from Microsoft using UpdatePanel:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386421(v=vs.100).aspx

Here is another example doing it at a lower level with jquery:

http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/jquery_ui_mvc_progressbar.ashx

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is here:

```
double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100
```

should be:

```
 double percentage = (bytesIn / totalBytes) * 100
```

the first part has always integral part=0

this means that:

```
Math.Truncate(bytesIn / totalBytes * 100)
```

will get you 0